# How to make an FTP hyperlink over TLS/SSL

Tags: ftp, ssl, filezilla

I've see ftp links that look like this

```
ftp://user@example.com/file.pdf
```

But it only works for unencrypted ftp. How can I link someone to a file on my filezilla ftp server that requires TLS/SSL to connect?

Comment: Have you tried using ftps://user@example.com/file.pdf - note that this may not be supported as it's not an official standard  and may only work with tools that recognise it. It is an implicit link and tools written using .Net framework would probably not be able to connect as they rely on an explicit connection.

Update: Check the following link from FileZilla project: 
https://wiki.filezilla-project.org/FTP_over_TLS

Comment: Apparently browsers do not support FTP over SSL. You need a proper FTP client to do that. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/robert_mcmurray/2008/09/24/ftp-clients-part-1-web-browser-support/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not appear to be possible. Browsers don't currently support the `ftpes://` and `ftps://` protocols. If you want a clickable link to a shared file, you'd best put it on a web server and transmit over HTTPS.

Answer (score 2):

FileZilla supports `ftpes://` (explicit TLS/SSL) and `ftps://` (implicit TLS/SSL) protocol prefixes.

Though I do not actually understand how FileZilla relates to hyperlinks, as I do not think that FileZilla can handle URL hyperlinks.